# Lineage OS for smartphones in 2020 under $100?

Tags: android

What are options in 2020 for (used) cheapest Lineage OS compatible but still supported phones?

- Motorola G4 is cheap but no more supported

While Motorola G4 is no more supported, are there recent experiences that a private build is working?

Answer (score 1):

> @K7AAY

The OP asked for a device for $100.

I think that he won't have much luck acquiring a OnePlus 5-7,Google Pixel XL, Essential, Xiaomi F1 Pocophone.. :3

In any case.

> @J.Doe

On https://www.xda-developers.com/ can you compare some of the smartphones on the list above against the regarding sub-forums on Xda.Many of devices have so-called 'unofficial' Lineage OS support, which have basically the same features.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

No information is available here regarding private builds of Lineage OS for the Motorola G4.

Device support by an OS is shown at the [OS website](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/), from which I filtered out the devices no longer supported to make the list which follows. This list shows manufacturer, model name, codename, and if it isn't a phone, its form factor.

Since we don't know where you are, and may not be able to check the market in your locale even if we did know, please instead check your own market pricing for these supported devices.

ZUK Z1  ham
ZUK Z2 Plus z2_plus
Yandex  Phone   Amber
Xiaomi  Mi 5    gemini
Xiaomi  Mi 5s   capricorn
Xiaomi  Mi 5s Plus  natrium
Xiaomi  Mi 6    sagit
Xiaomi  Mi 8    dipper
Xiaomi  Mi A1   tissot
Xiaomi  Mi MIX  lithium
Xiaomi  Mi MIX 2    chiron
Xiaomi  Mi MIX 2S   polaris
Xiaomi  Mi Note 2   scorpio
Xiaomi  Mi Note 3   jason
Xiaomi  Poco F1 beryllium
Xiaomi  Redmi 3S/3X land
Xiaomi  Redmi 4(X)  santoni
Xiaomi  Redmi Note 4    mido
Wileyfox    Swift   crackling
Sony    Xperia XA2  pioneer
Sony    Xperia XA2 Ultra    discovery
Sony    Xperia Z3   z3
Sony    Xperia Z3 Compact   z3c
Samsung Galaxy A3 (2016)    a3xelte
Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016)    a5xelte
Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017)    a5y17lte
Samsung Galaxy A7 (2017)    a7y17lte
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE (N9005/P) hlte
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE (N9008V)  hltechn
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE (N900K/L/S)   hltekor
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 LTE (N900T/V/W8)  hltetmo
Samsung Galaxy S III Neo (Dual SIM) s3ve3gds
Samsung Galaxy S III Neo (Samsung Camera)   s3ve3gjv
Samsung Galaxy S III Neo (Sony Camera)  s3ve3gxx
Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505/G, SGH-I337M, SGH-M919) jfltexx
Samsung Galaxy S4 (SCH-I545)    jfltevzw
Samsung Galaxy S4 (SCH-R970, SPH-L720)  jfltespr
Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-I337)    jflteatt
Samsung Galaxy S4 Active    jactivelte
Samsung Galaxy S4 Value Edition (GT-I9515/L)    jfvelte
Samsung Galaxy S5 Active    klteactivexx
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE (G9006V/8V)   kltechn
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE (G900AZ/F/M/R4/R7/T/V/W8,S902L)   klte
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE (G900I/P) kltedv
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE (G900K/L/S)   kltekor
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE (SCL23)   kltekdi
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE Duos (G9006W/8W)  kltechnduo
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE Duos (G900FD/MD)  klteduos
Samsung Galaxy S5 LTE-A lentislte
Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo   s5neolte
Samsung Galaxy S5 Plus  kccat6
Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 8.0 Wi-Fi (2016)  gts28vewifi Tablet
Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 9.7 Wi-Fi (2016)  gts210vewifi    Tablet
Realme  3 Pro   RMX1851
Razer   Phone   cheryl
OPPO    F1 (International)  f1f
OPPO    Find 7a/s   find7
OPPO    R5/R5s (International)  r5
OPPO    R7 Plus (International) r7plus
OPPO    R7s (International) r7sf
OnePlus OnePlus 2   oneplus2
OnePlus OnePlus 3 / 3T  oneplus3
OnePlus OnePlus 5   cheeseburger
OnePlus OnePlus 5T  dumpling
OnePlus OnePlus 6   enchilada
OnePlus OnePlus 6T  fajita
OnePlus OnePlus 7 Pro   guacamole
OnePlus OnePlus One bacon
Nubia   Z17 nx563j
Nextbit Robin   ether
Motorola    Moto G7 river
Motorola    Moto X 2014 victara
Motorola    Moto X4 payton
Motorola    Moto Z  griffin
Motorola    Moto Z2 Force   nash
LG  G2 (AT&T)   d800
LG  G2 (Canadian)   d803
LG  G2 (International)  d802
LG  G2 (T-Mobile)   d801
LG  G3 (AT&T)   d850
LG  G3 (Canada) d852
LG  G3 (International)  d855
LG  G3 (Korea)  f400
LG  G3 (Sprint) ls990
LG  G3 (T-Mobile)   d851
LG  G3 (Verizon)    vs985
LG  G5 (International)  h850
LG  G5 (T-Mobile)   h830
LG  G5 (US Unlocked)    rs988
LG  V20 (AT&T)  h910
LG  V20 (Global)    h990
LG  V20 (Sprint)    ls997
LG  V20 (T-Mobile)  h918
LG  V20 (US Unlocked)   us996
LG  V20 (Verizon)   vs995
Lenovo  P2  kuntao
Lenovo  Yoga Tab 3 Plus LTE     YTX703L Tablet
Lenovo  Yoga Tab 3 Plus Wi-Fi   YTX703F Tablet
LeEco   Le 2    s2
LeEco   Le Max2 x2
LeEco   Le Pro3 / Le Pro3 Elite zl1
Huawei  Honor 5X    kiwi
Huawei  Honor View 10   berkeley
Huawei  P20 Pro charlotte
HTC One (M8)    m8
HTC One (M8) Dual SIM   m8d
Google  Nexus 6 shamu   Phablet
Google  Pixel   sailfish
Google  Pixel XL    marlin
Fairphone   FP2 FP2
Essential   Essential PH-1  mata
BQ  Aquaris X   bardock
BQ  Aquaris X Pro   bardockpro
BQ  Aquaris X2  zangya
BQ  Aquaris X2 Pro  zangyapro
ASUS    Zenfone 3   zenfone3
ASUS    Zenfone 6 (ZS630KL) I01WD
ASUS    Zenfone Max Pro M1  X00TD
ASUS    Zenfone Max Pro M2  X01BD

Answer (score 0):

The OnePlus 3 (maybe 3T) was a very solid phone (had one), and it still supported.